# AddressCountryRegion table in ax 2012 R3

Tags: axapta, addressbook, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

My form in ax 2009 is using method in table AddressCountryRegion::type but in 2012 r3 this table is prefixed as DEL so I wonder what is the equivalent of this table,method and enumeration in ax 2012r3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new name is `LogisticsAddressCountryRegion`. If you need a human name, you will have to look in `LogisticsAddressCountryRegionTranslation`.

Or use the view `LogisticsAddressCountryRegionNameView`.

For the full view see [the white paper](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/E/3/4E36B655-568E-4D4A-B161-152B28BAAF30/Implementing_the_Address_Book_Framework_for_Microsoft_Dynamics_AX_Applications_AX2012.pdf).